# How to intercept Drupal BigPipe output or js-bottom-placeholder?

Tags: drupal, drupal-modules

I need to intercept (hook) and alter the output (json) prepared by the function `sendPlaceholders()` of `core/modules/big_pipe/src/Render/BigPipe.php` that is

```
...
$json = $ajax_response->getContent();

$output = <<<EOF
<script type="application/vnd.drupal-ajax" data-big-pipe-replacement-for-placeholder-with-id="$placeholder_id">
$json
</script>
EOF;

$this->sendChunk($output);
```

Is it possible and how to?

Or at least to intercept and alter the output of

```
<js-bottom-placeholder token="{{ placeholder_token }}">
```

(Or BigPipe overrides it anyway?)

Preferred a solution in a theme preprocess function

Drupal 10.x

Answer (score 0):

I managed to do it via `hook_js_alter()` since it processed here: https://git.drupalcode.org/project/drupal/-/blob/11.x/core/lib/Drupal/Core/Asset/AssetResolver.php#L282